# how can add I calculate the average rating and add this from my column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want to search through average rating.so, i have an two table first     restaurant table and second user rating .search function to get restaurant list.
search query to calculate average rating by there rest id and add them into my restaurant table column .

---

```
restaurant tabel
user_id | rest_name | rest_logo | fname| lname |user_type(2 customer 4 Restaurant owner)

rating
rate_id | user_id | rest_id |rate



 public function getRestaurantLists($post='',$position='', $item_par_page=''){

    if(!empty($post['rest_catid'])){
        $data2 = array(
            'rest_catid' => $post['rest_catid']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data2);
    }
    if(!empty($post['cuisine'])){
        $data3 = array(
            'cuisine' => $post['cuisine']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data3);
    }

    if(!empty($post['city'])){
        $data4 = array(
            'city' => $post['city']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data4);
    }

    if(!empty($post['keyword'])){
        $data5 = array(
            'keyword' => $post['keyword']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data5);
    }

     if(!empty($post['star'])){
        $data5 = array(
            'star' => $post['star']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data5);
    }

    //echo $post['star'];
    $sql = '';

    $sql .= "SELECT  tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.rest_name,tbl_rating.rate,tbl_users.rest_logo, tbl_users.address, tbl_users.city,
    tbl_rest_category.rest_category_name
    FROM tbl_users
    LEFT JOIN tbl_rest_category
    ON tbl_rest_category.rest_category_id = tbl_users.rest_category_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_rest_cuisine
    ON tbl_rest_cuisine.rest_id = tbl_users.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_rating
    ON tbl_rating.rest_id = tbl_users.user_id   
    WHERE user_status = 1 AND user_type = 4 ";

    if($this->session->userdata('rest_catid')!== FALSE){
       $sql .= " AND tbl_users.rest_category_id = '".$this->session->userdata('rest_catid')."' ";
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('cuisine')!== FALSE){
       $sql .= " AND tbl_rest_cuisine.cuisine_id IN(".$this->session->userdata('cuisine').") ";
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('city')!== FALSE){
       $sql .= " AND tbl_users.city = '".$this->session->userdata('city')."' ";
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('keyword')!== FALSE){
       $sql .= " AND tbl_users.rest_name LIKE '%".$this->session->userdata('keyword')."%' ";
    }
     if($this->session->userdata('star')!== FALSE){
       $sql .= " AND tbl_rating.rate IN(".$this->session->userdata('star').") ";
    }
    $sql.=" GROUP BY tbl_users.user_id ";

    if(!empty($item_par_page)){
       $sql .= " LIMIT ".$position .",".$item_par_page;  
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);    
   //echo $this->db->last_query();die;
    if($query->num_rows>0){
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unusual/unlikely that this is something that you'd want to store rather than calculate 'on the fly'

Comment: @Strawberry : My guess too, agree with you

Comment: How can `rest category id` be a column in `users`? Likewise for cuisine. This is bonkers

Comment: Yeah, and I don't see why you have user_id / user_type in table restaurant...

Comment: i have managing a single table for customers and restaurant  by there user type( 2 for its customer and 4 for its restaurant).it is a filter search

Answer (score 0):

To get the average rating for a restaurant :

```
SELECT AVG(rate) FROM rating WHERE rest_id = {rest_id}
```

To put it in restaurant table, add a new column (let's say avg_rating, type FLOAT) and :

```
UPDATE restaurant
SET avg_rating = (SELECT AVG(rate) FROM rating WHERE rest_id = restaurant.id)
```

Don't forget tu update it each time you have a new vote (trigger or programatically).

**Anyway, maybe you don't need to store that ?** Especially if you want to get the average rating with filters.
You can take the first query and just add your filters.

Comment: but when i trigger this update.and in update how to get the restaurant id
 WHERE rest_id = restaurant.id

Comment: The update will update all restaurant.
If you need specific restaurant, replace restaurant.id by the id you want.